# Is it possible to change the return type of a function

Tags: c#, return-type

Is it possible to have a function that takes (int n,bool wantall) and returns a different type based on the bool?
The example that made me think about this was generate the fibonacci numbers.
If wantall = true, then return an array (or list) of the first n numbers, else, just return the nth number.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could use a custom return type, like `FibonacciResult` that contains properties for both the list and the single number result.  But I agree with the posts below that this is not a good idea.

Comment: *"If wantall = true, then return an array (or list) of the first n numbers, else, just return the nth number. Is there a way to do this?"* -- sorry, this is just a bad design and shouldn't be used in practice. Its better to have two methods, `GetFibs(int count)` and `GetNthFib(int n)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't change the return type.

For your example, ideally you should have different overloads for what you are talking about

```
GetFirstFibonacciNumbers(int count)
GetSingleFibonacciNumber(int nth)
```

Passing in a `bool` for this is just ugly.

But if you insist on a single method

```
IEnumerable<int> GetFibonacciNumbers(int n, bool wantall) {
    if(!wantall) {
        return new[] { GetSingleFibonacciNumber(n); }
    }
    else {
        return GetFirstFibonacciNumbers(n);
    }
}
```

But, please, don't do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
public Object foo(int n, bool wantall)
{
    // you can return whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return `object` or some other type that all possible return types inherit from, but other than that, you can't change the return type on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Return an `object`, or a wrapper that provides an enum that tips you off to what is actually inside the object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) return type

Answer (score 0):

No, method contracts are defined at compile time and cannot be changed at runtime.

One option would be to return an object type, but the use of the object type in such a circumstance is generally considered to be un-type-safe, so the best practice is to avoid it..

I see a couple ways of handling this:--

1. Always return an array, but only populate it with one item if wantall=false.
2. Use separate methods for the single value and the array of values.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason mentions, using bool for your specific example is not a great idea.  However, the issue is really moot using Generics: for instance (using your specific example)

```
public List<int> FibSequence(int i, int? n)
{
    List<int> fibSeq = new List<int>();
    //Calculate fib sequence
    if(n != null)
    {
       return new List<int>() { fibSeq[n] };
    }
    return fibSeq;
}
```

Again, for this particular purpose, it's not great, but there are a fair number of times when I have had to get "All of X" when "All" turned out only to be 1 (which would drop the nullable int parameter, but the code itself is very similar).  Then your code just handles the generic list that's returned, and considers if it has multiple elements or not.

Comment: I could also have just set it to the first element of the array, but that was not really the point